# better display of incoming email messages in database

Tags: email, wysiwyg

Incoming email (e.g. mail imported into the database via the fetch_activities scheduled job) is stored in the database as plain text (which is great).

However, when you view an inbound email activity, it is displayed without any line breaks, which makes it very difficult to read, especially if there is a long reply thread.

Does anyone know of a way to tell CiviCRM to add line breaks (nl2br or something) for just this one activity type? Or any other suggestions on improving the readability of incoming email messages?

Comment: This was fixed about 2 years ago I think, and I just checked now and it displays legibly with line breaks for me. Are you seeing it for all emails or just some?

Comment: Agree with @Demerit. I think the related gitlab for this problem is https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/2. Can you mention the Civi version or upgrade if you're using any version below 4.7.31?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @demerit and @jitendra for your help!

It turns out, the answer is: don't change the label for the Incoming Email activity type :).

The user changed it from Incoming Email to just Email. Changing the label should definitely not break things - but since [this issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1116) is still open, it does.

So, in the short term, I'll change the label back. In the long term, getting 1116 fixed would be ideal.